# Extract previous week from current date

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table where I need to find previous week from current date as true or false. Please see the table below.
[image]

Comment: please provide more details - sample of input data, expected output and logic with example - what does it mean `previous week from current date as true or false`? give some example of what you mean!

Comment: @Mikhali, Sample data is attached. For example first row: Report date is 18/06/2020 and ReportWeekCommencing is 14/06/2020. So weekToDate is True. Now I need to find if this report date is true or false for previous week. Obviously in this case false. Basically I need to consider both ReportDate and ReportWeekCommencing column. Week commenced from every Sunday. ReportFinancialYear is from Oct-Sept and Q1 is Oct-Dec,Q2 is Jan-Mar and so on.

Comment: can you clarify why on 7th row weekToDate is `false`? it looks to me to be a `true` as both dates are the same

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, yes it's supposed to be true. I'll have a look on this column. Can you pls assist me on the Previous week column.

Comment: sure. see the answer :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ReportDate, 
  ReportWeekCommencing,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ReportDate) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ReportWeekCommencing) AS WeekToDate,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE_SUB(ReportDate, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ReportWeekCommencing) AS PreviousWeek
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-06-18' ReportDate, DATE '2020-06-14' ReportWeekCommencing UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-03-31', '2020-03-29' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-03-29', '2020-03-22' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-03-24', '2020-03-22' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-03-27', '2020-03-10' 
)
SELECT 
  ReportDate, 
  ReportWeekCommencing,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ReportDate) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ReportWeekCommencing) AS WeekToDate,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE_SUB(ReportDate, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ReportWeekCommencing) AS PreviousWeek
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row ReportDate  ReportWeekCommencing    WeekToDate  PreviousWeek     
1   2020-06-18  2020-06-14          true            false    
2   2020-03-31  2020-03-29          true            false    
3   2020-03-29  2020-03-22          false           true     
4   2020-03-24  2020-03-22          true            false    
5   2020-03-27  2020-03-10          false           false
```